# Float error when using matplotlib for a graph

Tags: matplotlib, graph

I've created a GUI that performs integration and now I'm trying to create a simple graphical output of the user inputted function. I got the set up for the matplotlib but I get a float error. If anyone can help that would be great, here's my code with this error
File "C:\Users\SJRow\source\repos\GUI\GUI\GUI.py", line 51, in trapezium
y = self.finalinput(z)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

```
  def trapezium(self):
    def function(x):
          resultinput=self.EquationInput.text()
          self.finalinput=eval(resultinput)
          return self.finalinput
    lower = self.ScrollLower.value()
    upper = self.ScrollUpper.value()
    strips=self.ScrollStrip.value()
    h=float(upper-lower)/strips
    self.result=0.5*function(lower)+0.5*function(upper)
    for i in range(1,strips):
        self.result+=function(lower+i*h)
    self.result=h*self.result
    self.result=str(self.result)
    self.CalcOutput.setText(self.result)
    z = np.arange(lower+5,upper+5,100)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    y = self.finalinput(z)
    plt.plot(z, y, 'r')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

self.finalinput is of float type. You can't pass z as argument.

Modify your function:

```
def function(x):
     resultinput=self.EquationInput.text()
     self.finalinput=eval(resultinput.replace('x',str(x)))
     return self.finalinput
```

And then map this function with z

```
y = list(map(function, z))
plt.plot(z, y, 'r')
```

It should work.

Comment: what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: It not clear what you want to achieve. But you are passing a numpy array to a float variable. Can you tell me what is eval here?  I think you want self.finalinput to behave as a functional variable.

Comment: I want to be able to plot a graph of the user inputted function e.g 3x+2, the code is a snippet from a working gui since I didn't think people would want to read through a tonne of code The eval is used to change the users input expression into a mathematical function to act upon.

Comment: Consider upvoting and making as accepted answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Your fix has created a graph output for me (so that works) but I'm just getting a very specific part of the graph with no line for the equation

Comment: While passing text for eval() you have to keep in mind of proper format  eg. 3x+2 is not right format. Instead you must pass 3*x+2. For more info https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#:~:text=When%20you%20call%20eval()%20with%20a%20string%20as%20an,Parse%20expression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230412/discussion-between-sandeep-maurya-and-sj-rowell).